# UITableView and GADBannerView

Tags: xamarin.ios, admob, uitableview

I was trying to implement a TableView where between the rows of my source I would like to insert a GADBannerView (sponsored ads by Google AdMob). I currently have a datasource which every time I come to the end add 10 elements like an infinite scroll.

My intention would be to insert an element GADBannerView every 6 rows. How could I do?

**UPDATE**

As suggested

```cs
public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
{
    return (int)Math.Floor (Convert.ToDouble(ViewModel.ListElements.Count / 6) )+ ViewModel.ListElements.Count;
}

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if(indexPath.Row % 6 == 0 && indexPath.Row > 0){
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (BannerGATableCell.Key) as BannerGATableCell ?? BannerGATableCell.Create ();

        _bannerView.LoadRequest (GADRequest.Request);
        cell.AddSubview(_bannerView);

        return cell;
    }

    if (indexPath.Row >= 6) {
        return base.GetCell (tableView,  NSIndexPath.FromRowSection((int)(indexPath.Row - (int)(indexPath.Row / 6)),0));
    }


    return base.GetCell (tableView, indexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know how many banners will fit into your source.

- Say you have 14 rows in total in your source.
- Every 6th row is supposed to be a banner.
- number of banners == (int)Math.Floor(14f / 6) == 2

So we have one banner at row 6 (index 5) and one at 12 (index 11).

In your `RowsInSection()` method add **2** to the number of rows you have (for the banners).

Then in `GetCell()` check if it is time to inject a banner:

```
if(indexPath.Row % 6 == 0 && indexPath.Row > 0)
{
  var bannerCell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(SOME_SPECIAL_CELL_ID) as BannerCell;
  if(bannerCell == null) 
  {
     ...
  }

  bannerCell.SetBannerView(SomeHelper.GetBannerView());
  return bannerCell;
}
```

`BannerCell` would be a subclass of `UITableViewCell` you have to create that allows setting the banner. You can also use a normal cell and add the banner view to the `ContentView` of the cell. But don't forget to remove the subview first.

Comment: What's wrong with the override? Only thing I see: you're not supposed to call `base.GetCell()` but rather create your cell.

Comment: Sorry I used wrong term. I wanted to say that in this way the elements are always of same number, and the BannerCell replaces the cell's DataSource rather than inserted between the sixth and seventh

Comment: Sure, you have to adjust the index of the real data. Data index = row - number of injected banners so far